# Extracting text from span

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I have a problem regarding a span tag, that has no id or class.
The larger approach is to extract the text between "ITEM 1. BUSINESS" TO "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS" from the link below. However, I can't figure out a way to find this part, because the span it is in, has no id nor a class I can search for (only the parent div the span is in: `div = soup.find("div", {"id": "dynamic-xbrl-form"})`.

This code does not work, sadly: `#text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', soup.get_text()).replace('\n', '')`

Here is my approach:

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/934549/000093454919000017/actg2018123110-k.htm#s62CF0831C63E51C2BEF33F4163F1DE65'
raw = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw.content)

div = soup.find("span", {"id": ... })
print(div.txt)
```

Do you have any ideas or hints?

Thanks a lot
Julius

Answer (score 1):

As @Gagan said , The content of website are loaded from Javascript. You need to use `Selenium`

Using Selenium is more powerful than other Python function .I used ChromeDriver so If you don't install yet You can install it in

> http://chromedriver.chromium.org/

```
from  selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'your driver path'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get("https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/934549/000093454919000017/actg2018123110-k.htm#s62CF0831C63E51C2BEF33F4163F1DE65")
datas = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span") // use # or . for class or id name like span#id_name , span.class_name

for spans in datas:
    print(spans.text)
```

You can also  get all source

```
print (browser.page_source)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried the selenium approach as well before, but with ```find_elements_by_xpath```, however I was not able with this particular link (sec.gov) to find any div with "class: col-sm-12" or "id=dynamic-xbrl-form". Although the div with those attributes is clearly in the html code. To be specific, I used this code:
```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dynamic-xbrl-form']")```
But I only get "Unable to locate element" errors. Usually this does get me the right result. Sadly the span I am actually looking for has neither "id" nor "class"!

Answer (score 0):

The content of this page are loaded from `JavaScript`, you cannot use `BeautifulSoup` for this. Make use of `selenium` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know which function I need? Something with "find"?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am checking using id of span tag, this solved mine:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/hackerv728'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('span', id='fb-timeline-cover-name')
for title in titles:
    print(title.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work. Also the div.text is not a valid method.